# 42601 ERROR: syntax error at or near "NULLS" using unique NULLS NOT DISTINCT on PostgreSQL 14.4 Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, indexing, null, unique

I have a situation where I want my composite field null check to be UNIQUE.  So I'm using the UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT syntax as follows:

```
create table codes
(
    id       serial primary key,
    code     text not null,
    sub_code text null,
    unique nulls not distinct (code,sub_code)
);
```

In this example the code can be entered again if it has a sub_code but only one version of codes can exist without a sub_code

It looks like PostgreSQL is rejecting the word nulls.  Any ideas why?  Is there a configuration to turn this syntax on?

Comment: That syntax requires Posgres 15 which is not released yet

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the CONSTRAINT keyword like this:

```
create table codes
(
    id       serial primary key,
    code     text not null,
    sub_code text null,
    CONSTRAINT uq_sub_code
        UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (sub_code)
);
```

Comment: Same error, copying your line exactly:[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "NULLS" Position: 149

Comment: is there any chance that you could upgrade postgreSQL to version 15? Did not see the version of your postgres, the UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT only works from version 15

Comment: I could on my machine but not in production, my mistake, I saw a chart on-line that implied  the feature was already implemented but just now being formalised.  Thanks for making me look further on the internet.